# Is it fair that somebody rejects already accepted answer in SO because I did not answer the subsequent questions posted later?

Tags: discussion, support, accepted-answer

My question title is quite elaborate. Recently I answered a question which was initially accepted by OP. Now am completely aware of the fact that nobody can ask the OP to accept the answer and it's completely OPs wish to reject and accept whichever answer he thinks appropriate.

But here in this case,  I answered it which I believe was correct to second that believe I got two up votes as well. Immediately after that OP accepted the answer.

Later he started posting questions which I did not notice and did not answer that question. OP updated his question again I wasn't aware so I did not answer!

Now OP left me a message as "you don't know?" And rejected my answer and accepted another answer which was posted way later then I did n does not provide complete answer either.

Now I know that nobody can ask OP to accept a specific answer but isn't it in unfair that I spent my effort and time answering a question now OP rejects my answer just because I didn't answer his subsequent questions. Am I entitled to answer all the subsequent questions of OP?!? I know proper answer will be appreciated over the time by community n am not concerned about his acceptance of answer but I personally feel behaviour of this sort demoralising to constantly contributing community member

Link to the question I mentioned above : 
[Convert a UICollectionView function to a UITableView function (Swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47222416/convert-a-uicollectionview-function-to-a-uitableview-function-swift/47222528#47222528)

Comment: Users who behave in this way are "help vampires"

Comment: So all u r saying is that as a member of so having answered 300+ questions in 1 and half year deserves this and in one and half year I was just time passing and only people posting questions have all rights and someone who is contributing have no right even to raise a voice against it. True sir I should have figured out a better way to waste time rather than being a part of this community if that's how this community roles I regret I ever thought of contributing back to community :(

Comment: This sort of behavior is extremely rampant among institutional software customers. Many seem to think that change request/bug tracking software is actually some form of message-passing system and will gleefully hit "reject" in order to add new requirements to that change request you just implemented. Time-to-completion metrics? Who cares when there is a customer who needs their new changes *now*! Management certainly doesn't, and tells the developers to stop whining about misuse of the ticket system and get those new changes implemented right away!

Comment: @Robert Columbia : thanks for sympathising. I am not concerned about one acceptance I can spend a little more time and earn much more than that. All I am saying is this community should have some mechanism to tell such people that that's not how u behave and should have some degree of morality before expecting a answer from community

Comment: There's no inherent fairness in the distribution of accept votes. The accept vote is the OPs to do with as they please, full stop. We as a community do not handle user behaviour. We handle content. Diamond moderators handle behaviour. If somone's behaviour is concerning you, you could use a mod flag and let the mods handle it how they deem necessary. In this case that would probably be declined though.

Comment: @tiny-giant: I understand was just hoping that as there is a mechanism to revert intentional series down votes there could have been some guidelines SO could establish to imply some guidelines to mentor such behaviour of OP. But then that's ok if that's how SO rolls. Might affect my involvement in future to contribute back to community but I believe community is much bigger to care for an individual contributor

Comment: That mechanism is a mod flag. Don't worry about correcting others behaviour yourself, that's not your job, nor is it your place. We elect diamond moderators for that job.

Comment: @Tiny Giant : I agree I shouldn't be worried about correcting somebody's behaviour nor I have that right. Thank you for taking time and commenting to my question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not accepting an answer to begin with because an asker edited in some additional questions to their question is one thing. Accepting an answer, *then* deciding that it wasn't enough and editing the question then unaccepting your answer? This can be either outright disrespectful, or simply a case of someone not understanding how the accept feature works and when to use it, especially in the case of underspecified questions (which is why it can sometimes be dangerous to answer what might seem like a crystal-clear and straightforward question, and why we *strongly* discourage [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) to begin with).

As curt as their "you don't know?" is (there's no denying that), this case does look more like the latter to me. No, it's probably not fair to you, but people make mistakes. What can we do? We'll just have to live with it. Like you said, this is just one accept, so it shouldn't be hard to move on from. Yeah, it stings a little, it's probably not what you wanted to hear, but that's just how it is. I feel your frustration, I've been there.

If a user is clearly abusing the edit and accept/unaccept feature with the intention of openly disrespecting answerers and generally being a pain (based on their comments or their edits for example), flag their question for moderator attention — we'll be interested in having a look.

Comment: I completely agree sir! I believe it's a momentary frustration should be able to move on with that anyway :) probably as suggested in comments above I should not be worried about teaching somebody the correct behaviour and I don't have that power either. Thank you for sympathising and appreciate ur effort to take time and answer my question. Hence up vote and accepting answer now